C.V. For PhD Application
I will be applying to a PhD in English program in about a year and a half. One of the admissions requirements is a C.V.
Firstly, I am not sure of what to include in my C.V. Additionally, I feel as if my C.V. Is unremarkable.
Any ideas or tips for creating a professional C.V., what to include to position myself well for the program, or things to do to improve my C.V. (I.e., volunteer work, conference attendance, etc.)?

The CV of nearly everyone applying for grad school is pretty unremarkable.
